# Execute large number of commands via SSH

Tags: shell, ssh

Okay so I have a script that needs to execute a bunch of commands via SSH, however I'd also like to allow it to run the same commands locally if the target provided is a local path rather than a host-name.

Now I can determine whether I'm operating locally or not without too much trouble but I have a really complex set of commands to run, far more than is suitable for supplying as an argument to ssh directly.

What I would like to do is something like:

```
if [ -n "$HOST" ]
    then
        ssh "$HOST"
fi

# Run some commands
# exit
```

However there are obvious issues such as how I would pass the appropriate variables and exit without causing the script to end early when targeted locally. So I'm not sure if this is possible, is there a way to do anything like the above using normal shell commands that are actually being run remotely?

If not, the alternative would be for me to extract the commands I need to run into their own shell script, and ensure that my ssh command copies the shell script across (if it doesn't exist already) then runs it, but I'm not sure how to do that either? I'm familiar with basic unix commands, but not something like this!

Anyway, I'd appreciate any recommendations on the best way to do this, with a detailed example if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Trust isn't actually an issue as I've set up public key authentication for passwordless SSH.

Anyway, it seems that my best option is to extract the commands into a shell script and send it to the server as needed. That said, I'm thinking here documents might also allow me to do it without sending a script, though sending the script when required is probably the more efficient option for the workload I require.

Here's an example of what I was thinking of for a here document:

```
if [ -n "$HOST" ]; then ssh "$HOST" <<- 'REMOTE_SESSION'; fi

    # Some commands

if [ -n "$HOST" ]; then REMOTE_SESSION; fi
```

The main difficulty is making sure that the commands within the remote session "block" are structured correctly, since any stdin and stdout will be on the remote server if the SSH connection was opened.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at remote shell.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Shell There are some issues though, like how to handle security. Storing the password in a plain text file is not what you want. You also need to set up some kind of trust between the computers. Check your local man page if you are on linux/unix.